# hyperlink button

Tags: css, forms, button, hyperlink

I am trying to format a reply button:

```
.replyBtn {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.replyBtn:hover {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.replyBtn:link {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.replyBtn:active {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.replyBtn:visited {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

The background color changes.  The only thing that is wrong is that it shows the hyperlink color with the underline(which is something i don't want it to have).  also, the color of the text should change to white on hover over...

Comment: Remember the phrase 'LoVe HAte', your links should be styled in the order: `a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:hover`, `a:active`.

Comment: @DavidThomas whats up with all of the other letters in the phrase. I would find it hard to remember which letters are capital and which are not.

Comment: Well, I just find it an easier mnemonic than 'LVHA', and since that's how Eric Meyer phrased it the first time I came across the notion, that's the one I remember. It does, of course, omit the `a:focus` state, too.

Comment: haha interesting!  will have to try to remember that... at the moment, i have no other way! :p

Answer (score 0):

Add `a` infront of the class

```
a.replyBtn:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS works by order of specificity of the selectors used, and then, if two selectors are equally specific, in order of which came last. Reorder your CSS to:

```
.replyBtn {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.replyBtn:link {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.replyBtn:visited {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.replyBtn:hover {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.replyBtn:active {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

I'll point out that you seem to be styling the `.replyBtn` elements with a default and then over-riding those defaults in your `.replyBtn:link` styles. I realise you may have other element-types with the same class-name, but you should define the `a`/link-specific styles in the `.replyBtn:link`, so it forms the defaults for *all* of those links:

```
.replyBtn:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}

/* all the other stuff... */
```

---

**Edited** in response to the comment left in the comments, from the OP:

> try this: jsfiddle.net/CTxQs.

Well, given that your HTML mark-up is:

```
<div class="replyBtn"><a href="#btn_comment">Reply</a></div>​
```

Your CSS is wrong. This selector:

```
.replyBtn:link {
}
```

Selects an element of class-name `replyBtn` that is a link; this is all well and good and would work, if your `a` element had the class of `.replyBtn`. But it does not; the `a` element is a *child* element of the `.replyBtn` `div` element. Amend your selectors to the following:

```
.replyBtn { /* selects the div */
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.replyBtn a:link { /* selects the a that's a child of the div */
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.replyBtn a:visited {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.replyBtn a:hover {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.replyBtn a:active {
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px;
    font-size:12px;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CTxQs/11/).

Further reading, from Eric Meyer:

- [Who Ordered the Link States?](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/06/11/who-ordered-the-link-states/).
- [Link Specificity](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html).

Comment: so you're saying that ".element:link" gives a default to all elements?

Comment: It really should; so...I suspect something else is happening to interfere. Any chance you could post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce/demonstrate your problem? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), we only need to see the relevant parts required to demonstrate the problem. @droidus: no, I'm saying that `.element:link` gives a default to all links with the class-name of `element`. Unless those styles are overridden elsewhere (by `!important`, or by a more specific selector).

Comment: @droidus Try styling the `a` and not just the `div` http://jsfiddle.net/CTxQs/8/ Though I really know little about html and css it looked to work for me.

Comment: Look at the edited answer, the CSS following the `hr` is what you need. Follow through and check out the JS Fiddle demo, too.

Comment: that button doesn't do anything on hover over.  it's also the wrong color initially.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully applied my required behavior as

```
a:link.replyBtn, a:visited.replyBtn, 
a:active.replyBtn, a:hover.replyBtn {...}
```

On my page, all links are shown as expected i.e. with respect to their css classes. It is working on Chrome but not IE, still working on it...
Hope this would help